# how would you sort n sorted lists with average length K in O(n*log K) time?

Tags: algorithm

how would you sort n sorted lists with average length K in O(n*log K) time?

Comment: Do you mean merge and sort n sorted lists with average length K in O(n*log K) time?

Comment: Yes your right Brian, i exactly mean that

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but don't you have O(n*K) elements and every element needs to be read at least once so any algorithm should be at least O(n*K).

Comment: You're right, theycallhimtom (you should make it an answer).  If this were possible, you could merge two sorted lists in O(2 log K) = O(log K) time.  That would make regular merge sort O((log K)^2)!

Comment: You don't need to read every element. See my solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, the O(nlog(k)) is not possible, but here are a couple of algorithms on [this page](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?interview.11.439577.9) that accomplish your task efficiently; here is one:

> Take the first element of each list
>   and create a heap (of size k). Pop the
>   smallest element. Find the array from
>   the element came (let's say it came
>   from list number i). Take the next
>   element from list i and push it in
>   heap. For each element that go in the
>   merged list, we spent log(k) time. So
>   the time complexity is O(N*logk) where
>   N is total number of the elements in
>   all the K lists.
>
> -written by: [Abhishek Goyal](http://360.yahoo.com/reachagoyal)

Comment: thanks for your inputs Soldier and Abhishek. This is a proper solution

Comment: when you say its not possible can you provide a proof? Else, please say _I_ do not know of any such way. Statements like those without proof just stand in the way of progress.

Comment: @ldog: See comments on the question. If it were possible, then you could merge two sorted lists in O(log k), meaning that you could do a sub-linear merge of two lists, which clearly is not possible. It also implies comparison sorting in better than O(n log n), another thing that's been proven impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort is the key. Lets suppose N is the total number of elements to be united and K the number of containers containing them:

- You append all the sorted sequences in a single vector but remembering where you appended them. Better is if you append them sorted by the value of their first element, would speed up next passage.
- Then you merge in place pairs of sorted sequences (std::inplace_merge if you use C++). Every merge is Na + Nb so every step is N. You have to perform logK steps.

Hence NlogK.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible to achieve O(N*log(K)), but not in the worst case.

Consider sorting these lists:

```
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
{10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20},
{20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30}
```

My human brain can easily sort those lists without reading every value, so there should be an algorithm that can do the same. We need to merge while using a modified binary search to look for ranges of values.

In the worst case, you get O(N*K), because every value must be compared. Example:

```
{0,2,4,6,8},
{1,3,5,7,9}
```

Here is my solution in Go, which I would only use if I knew the sorted lists usually have overlap regions that are small relative to K:

```
// variation of binary search that finds largest
// value up to and including max
func findNext(a []int, imin int, vmax int) int {
    imax := len(a) - 1
    best := -1
    for imin <= imax {
        imid := imin + ((imax - imin) / 2)
        if a[imid] == vmax {
            return imid
        } else if a[imid] < vmax {
            best = imid
            imin = imid + 1
        } else {
            imax = imid - 1
        }
    }
    return best
}

func sortNSortedLists(in [][]int) []int {
    var out []int
    cursors := make([]int, len(in))
    for {
        // Find the array indices that have the smallest
        // and next to smallest value (may be same) at
        // their current cursor.
        minIdx1 := -1
        minIdx2 := -1
        minVal1 := math.MaxInt32
        minVal2 := math.MaxInt32
        for i, cursor := range cursors {
            if cursor >= len(in[i]) {
                continue
            }
            if in[i][cursor] < minVal1 {
                minIdx2 = minIdx1
                minVal2 = minVal1
                minIdx1 = i
                minVal1 = in[i][cursor]
            } else if in[i][cursor] < minVal2 {
                minIdx2 = i
                minVal2 = in[i][cursor]
            }
        }
        if minIdx1 == -1 {
            // no values
            break
        }
        if minIdx2 == -1 {
            // only one array has values, so append the
            // remainder of it to output
            out = append(out, in[minIdx1][cursors[minIdx1]:]...)
            break
        }

        // If inVal1 is smaller than inVal2,
        // append to output all values from minVal1 to minVal2 found in
        // the minIdx1 array, and update the cursor for the minIdx1 array.
        if minVal1 < minVal2 {
            firstCursor := cursors[minIdx1]
            lastCursor := findNext(in[minIdx1], firstCursor, minVal2)
            if lastCursor != -1 {
                out = append(out, in[minIdx1][firstCursor:lastCursor+1]...)
                cursors[minIdx1] = lastCursor+1
                continue
            }
        }
        // Append the single value to output
        out = append(out, minVal1)
        cursors[minIdx1]++
    }
    return out
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can adapt merge sort to do the job.  Merge sort takes advantage of the ease of merging already sorted lists into a new sorted list.

Comment: No you can't.  A merge is O(K).

Comment: Without defining it more it would be something like nK*log(nK), as you are basically just merging a long concatenated list of all the arrays.