# Show that n positive integers can be sorted in Nlogk time

Tags: algorithm

Show that n positive integers in the range 1 to k can be sorted in O(n log k) time.

I can only use Mergesort, since I know how to do it using a heap. This is not a HW problem, it's from Skiena's book.

I see that if I have K = 3, then in 3 steps i can merge the list; but does that suffice for an answer or 'showing'?

Comment: I think I am expected to only use merge sort, since the problem is under merge sort section

Comment: There is no reason in practice why one must restrict oneself to a specific sort function. StackOverflow is for practical programming problems, not theoretical ones.

Comment: Okay, can you explain to me how Radix sort will be N*Log(k)

Comment: `I see that if I have K = 3, then in 3 steps i can merge the list; but does that suffice for an answer or 'showing'?` "Show" here means "prove".

Comment: What I am trying to understand is, how do I prove that it will be nlogk. Perhaps you did not read the question. Please carefully read it Raymond Chen

Comment: Did it not occur you to check, say, Wikipedia to learn about radix sort?

Comment: Your not reading properly Raymond. The challenge here is using MERGESORT. Please read the wikipedia on Mergesort and then read the problem. If we have a problem in the say Los Angeles, the solution won't be to runaway to New York if you are in charge of fixing the LA problem.

Comment: @RichardMckenna: On Wikipedia, radix sort is O(kn), k is number of digits. Back to your problem, let's say your k has d digits, d = log (k), so the complexity is O(n log k).

Comment: As I noted, the mergesort restriction is not practical. StackOverflow is for practical programming problems, and in practice, you would be allowed to choose sort algorithms other than mergesort.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481819/how-would-you-sort-n-sorted-lists-with-average-length-k-in-onlog-k-time

Comment: How do you do it using a heap?

Comment: @IVlad here it is explained how http://stackoverflow.com/a/2482010/1786117

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?interview.11.439577.9) are a couple of ideas for efficient sorting. As user templatetypedef said, [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) may be what you are looking for.

Hope it helps

Comment: It's absolutely possible to sort in O(n log k) time - just use radix sort.