# Algorithm- What is the best way to sort "n" input files and produce a single output file

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I am working on the following algorithm:

**Input to program:** "n" input files containing numbers,with an assumption that each input file is sorted.

**Output to program**: A single output file containing all the elements in a sorted manner

For example:

n = 4

file1 = [1,5,6,9]

file2 = [2,8,10,15]

file3 = [3,7,9,11]

file4 = [2,4,6,8]

output = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,8,9,9,10,11,15]

**My approach:** Read the first element of each file, find the minimum among them and write it out to the output file. **However this is pretty slow and there are a set of constraints am bound by:**

**Memory:** The program needs to be scalable, the file size can extend up to 1.4GB so reading the entire file in memory is sort of not preferred

**Number of files**: The number of files can grow upto a large number which further induces performance penalties.

I am using C programming language to do this, so kindly give suggestions accordingly, and I cannot change my language.

Comment: This question has already been asked several times, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481819/how-would-you-sort-n-sorted-lists-with-average-length-k-in-onlog-k-time

Comment: I guess my question is more aimed towards getting a memory efficient solution, as mentioned I cannot read the entire file in memory so I was looking for some efficient way to do this without reading everything in memory which I would have to in case of heap sort etc. Thanks for any help

Comment: Simple buffering? Or double-buffering, if you want a concurrent solution to increase performance? Just match the size of the buffers to the memory-bounds you want your program to perform within.

Comment: The problem you want to solve is called an n-way merge. It is covered to great detail in TAOCP Vol. 3 “sorting and searching.”

Comment: @johnsmith If you would have read the linked answer, you would find that it only requires you to have one number from each file in memory at a time. Please read carefully before jumping to wrong conclusions.

Comment: As Karoly Horvath mentioned, a min heap is probably an optimal way of doing this, since the problem reduces to sorting `n` numbers, if every file contains only one number. Using a min heap achieves O(T log(n)) time complexity and O(n) space complexity, where T is the total length of all files.

Comment: @johnsmith assuming all numbers are stored as fixed size binary. 1) have two integer variables per file, an old index and a current index 2) set an arbitrary x value, depending on memory budget 3) do an on-disk binary search for every file to see where x is supposed to fall in every file, save results in respective current indices 4) load all files up until respective current indices, starting from old indices 5) merge and append result to output 6) wipe all memorized file chunks from memory, set oldindices = currentindices, increment x, redo.

Comment: Note that the min-heap is used to find the minimum element out of n elements from the n files. If n is large enough that finding the minimum element more than doubles the overall time to merge the files, then it might be better to merge the files in two passes, using a square_root(n) way merge. For example, if merging 256 files, it might be faster to do sixteen 16-way merges, then one 16 way merge of the sixteen files from the first pass.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are already sorted use a version of Merge Sort, which takes time O(n) to merge already sorted sets. Take the first two lists and merge them and continue this until there are no files left.

This should take time equal to O(nm) where n is the size of the files and m is the number of files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't see how this achieves O(nm) time complexity. It's O(nm^2), I'd say. Let's suppose that every file has length `1`, then your algo is the naive O(m^2) way to sort the `m` numbers.

Comment: @WhatsUp: Actually, I think O(nm) is correct (n is the total number of items, and m is the number of files). In the general case, you pass each file no more than m times. The pathological case of `m==n` (i.e. each file has length 1) is O(nm), which is the same as O(n^2) or O(m^2). In any case, the suggested algorithm is hugely inefficient considering, as you pointed out in comments on the question, that there is an O(n log m) solution, and no file is read more than once.

Comment: @WhatsUp: O(n) time to merge and you have to do that m-1 times so there are n*m operations. Thus O(nm).

Comment: @Jim Mischel: I wouldn't say O(nm) is hugely inefficient, since it is linear if n or m is bound by a constant (making it O(x*c) where x is the non-constant value of n or m and c is the constant). You are right though, if you use a heap then you can achieve a runtime of O(n * logm).

Comment: It's hugely inefficient. If you have a million items spread over a thousand files, `n*m` is a billion, whereas `n log m` is on the order of 10 million. Two orders of magnitude qualifies as "hugely inefficient." You can bound one of n or m by a constant and call it linear, but then you're just playing with words. Your "linear" algorithm is then theoretically and realistically slower than the O(n log m) algorithm, which is a rather unexpected result. If you bound *both* m and n by a constant, then you could say that the running time is constant. Which is technically true, but also absurd.

Comment: For external sorts, usually compare time is not included, only the number of file read write operations. The assumption is that the compare method (like min heap) is fast enough to keep the output file streaming (the input files run at 1/n of streaming rate), for reasonable n, like up to 16.

Comment: OK, so I misunderstood the sentence `where n is the size of the files`. I thought it was the size of each file. As @JimMischel said, it is then inefficient.

Comment: @rcgldr: Which makes the proposed algorithm even worse, because it reads and writes items multiple times, whereas the heap-based merge reads and writes each item only once.